# How to plot multiple samples on ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, random, graphing

I've run a for loop and taken multiple samples of data. I want to take the data I just got and turn in into a histogram using ggplot.

Here is my code:

```html
for (i in 1:1000){
  sample[1000]
  sample[i] <- mean(pop$y[sample.int(nrow(pop),5, replace = FALSE)])
  
}

ggplot(sample, aes(x = sample)) + geom_histogram(bins = 40)
```

I get this error message:
"Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."

Is there a way for me to take the sample array I have now and turn it into a histogram using ggplot? Anything helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into errors because `sample` is a function. I changed the object name to `samp`.

I created some arbitrary data to represent `pop$y`, as well.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(435) # repeatability with rnorm
pop = data.frame(y = rnorm(100, 10, 2)) # create pop data

# storage for the loop
samp = vector(length = 1000) # this can't be in the loop

for (i in 1:1000){
  samp[i] <- mean(pop$y[sample.int(nrow(pop),5, replace = FALSE)])
}

ggplot(data.frame(samp = samp), aes(x = samp)) + 
   geom_histogram(bins = 40)
```

It was a few minor changes to what you had. This is the histogram that was produced based on these inputs.

[image]